# How to work with an infinite data set in Swift using LazyCollection

Tags: arrays, swift, lazy-evaluation

I have a scenario where I need to get a subset of an infinite data set below is sample code:-

```
let result = (1...)
    .lazy
    .flatMap { value -> [Int] in
        return [1,2,3].map{ $0 + value }
    }.filter { ($0 > 100 && $0 < 200) }
```

How to fetch all values from '**result**' variable in Swift?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. Your question is clearly about Swift, so why tags Objective-C and Haskell? Also, only use the `iOS` tag for questions specific to that platform, this is a platform agnostic question only related to Swift.

Comment: Tagged Haskell because people in Haskell do solve this kind of problems. So if they can suggest some solution.

Comment: What do you man by “fetch all values”? How should a function detect that the sequence produces only finitely many elements? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Martin. I got your point that a filter on an infinite collection may yield infinite result.

Comment: @MartinR sure I got yur point. There is no definite answer for infinite array and applying filter to it.